# Realtime Code Collaboration That is Not Floobits

Tags: vim, terminal, git

So... I love Floobits. I use it in Sublime and I use it in vim. But my network currently does not play nicely with its port requests.

I'm looking for a desktop code collaboration system so that an internetfriend and I can code in the same file at the same time and not have to worry about collisions.

We need to have constant access to the files via a terminal session.

My plan was to come up with a python script that updates the codebase continuously (as frequently as possible) using git, and then a sublime plugin (we'll assume here everyone's using Sublime) that makes sure that the buffer is up to date with the files.  But that's bad.

Thoughts?

Comment: AFAIK, the code on your disk is never touched by those tools: only (parts of) the content of the buffer are exchanged between users because that's where the action is. One could work for two hours or more in Vim without ever writing the current buffer to disk or commiting anything. Your Git-based strategy seems inappropriate, slow and wasteful. Anyway, did you try [CoVim](https://github.com/FredKSchott/CoVim)? Also, why don't you contact the floobits guys to try to fix your network issues?

Comment: Hey @romainl, thanks for the tips!

I agree that the git idea is wasteful and *definitely* slow, but I can't think of anything else that would emulate it properly... I've already spoken to the Floobiters, and they were super helpful but it's definitely a native network issue. Meh.

Comment: CoVim doesn't work. Vim is not multi-threaded, we (I work at Floobits) have a patch to add timers which enable non-user driven events in vim. Sorry about your port issue, have you looked into maybe setting up an ssh tunnel?

Comment: I think you're better off either setting up some ssh tunnels, or maybe give tmate a try (pairing tweaked tmux)